# How to support smaller iPhone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, size, screen

How do I support the 3.5 inch screen size if I built my app originally for the 4 inch screen size? Thanks!

Comment: Well you have 2 options:

- you can either arrange everything for the smaller and larger screens(if you don't have many items, you can just calculate the difference)

- use constraints on the view for the 3.5 inch screen and then it will automatically adjust for the 4 inch screen.

Comment: Please do some searching before posting such a question. There are plenty of existing discussions on how to support different sized screens.

Answer (score 0):

I think this you have to take care of before designing for 4inch that you have to support 3.5 inch as well at the time of designing 4 inch you can support 3.5 inch through auto layout concept.